# How to change the colors for tag/branch names in git log?

Tags: git

When I run the command `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate` I see branch and tag names in color (I think since I set `color.ui` to `auto`). I like this, however a couple of the colors are very hard to read, especially yellow, since I have a white background.

I would like to change this, and I found (in the Git book under color.* here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) that you can change settings under `color.*` to further customize Git's colors. However, none of the 4 subsettings (`branch`, `diff`, `interactive`, and `status`) seem to affect the colors used by git log for branch and tag names. Is it possible to change these colors, and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git log --graph` column colors are configurable through:

```
log.graphColors
```

as documented (not very well) in [the `git config` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

[The default set](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L12-L23) is `red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, bold red, bold green, bold yellow, bold blue, bold magenta, bold cyan`.

The decoration names (`tag: tagname`, `HEAD`, branch names, and so on) are colored according to `color.decorate.slot`, where *`slot`* is one of `branch`, `remoteBranch`, `tag`, `stash`, or `HEAD`.  (This control setting was new in Git 1.7.2, so if you have Git 1.7.1 or older you don't have it.)

There are many more control knobs: search the `git config` documentation for the word `color`.

Comment: Thanks. So I should set graphColors to a set? How do I do that?

Comment: Follow the documentation link and search for `graphColors`; you will find this text: "A list of colors, separated by commas, that can be used to draw history lines in `git log --graph`." So, list the colors you want used, separated by commas. (That's why I spelled out the default color set the way I did. Maybe the edit I just made makes it stand out better?)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure why I glossed over the "separated by commas." Anyway, I tried it but it didn't have an effect. To clarify, I'm trying to change the colors used to display branch and tag names next to the logs. It looks like this setting only changes "history lines" - which is strange because those seem to only be black anyway.

Comment: My command was `git config --global log.graphColors "red,green,blue,magenta,cyan,bold red,bold green,bold blue,bold magenta,bold cyan"`

Comment: Sorry, I see now that my question was very poorly phrased since I didn't indicate that I was trying to change the colors for branch and tag names. I will fix it now.

Comment: Incidentally, you can also run `git config --global --edit` to bring up your configured editor on your configuration. I like to use this myself for making minor tweaks to existing configurations (well, admittedly I just run `vim ~/.gitconfig` :-) ).

Comment: Thanks, this works. One minor thing - it seems like HEAD defaults to a light blue that isn't possible to set with the available colors. Do you know how to set that?

Comment: The built in default for `HEAD` is `bold cyan`, which should match that particular light blue. Note that in modern Git you can also use a numeric color (0-255) and even a 24-bit red/green/blue triple using the `#RRGGBB` syntax (a la HTML; the two characters encode a 256-bit value in hexadecimal).

Comment: From the documentation: > that can be used to draw history lines. This does not answer the question about tags coloring

Comment: @TheGodfather: see the paragraph starting with `The decoration names ...`. (Perhaps I should have put that in at the top, but this answer is pretty short. Also the original question phrasing sounded like he wanted to change the graph line colors.)

Answer (score 13):

In my config I have `color.diff.commit` set to `yellow`. I just tested command

```
git -c color.diff.commit=green log
```

and the color of commit is surely changed to green. See my [.gitconfig](http://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/gitconfig.html) and (separately included) [colors](http://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/lib/config/git/) (also in a personal [git repo](http://git.phdru.name/?p=dotfiles.git;a=tree)).

*Upd*. For branch and tags colors you need to set `color.decorate.branch` and `color.decorate.tag`. Example (from my "light_bg" file):

```
[color "decorate"]
    HEAD = cyan
    branch = green
    tag = blue bold
```

Comment: I'm talking about the color of the log output. I think you're talking about the color of commit messages which is different, though I don't know what is meant by "log" at the end of your command.

Comment: My command is `git log` — i.e. exactly the command you want to configure colors for — with an additional config setting.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that my question was very poorly phrased since I didn't indicate that I was trying to change the colors for branch and tag names. I will fix it now.

Comment: You need to set `color.decorate.branch` and `color.decorate.tag`. See *update* in the answer.

Comment: color.decorate.tag is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!